# A key parameter in lower_bound of a set in c++

Tags: c++, set

How do I apply lower_bound to a set with a comparison function of my own creation in c++?
For example, I've written a comparison function that checks if a number is big enough, and then I need to perform a binary search on a set using a lower_bound in composition with the function I've written.

Comment: [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

Comment: You can't use a comparator as a predicate. Just give the limit of "big enough" as the value.

Comment: Please share the your code to explain your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually think, that i figured out what you trying to do.
I guess you want to use binary search in set limited with lower bound. If it's correct here is method:

```
template <typename T>
bool searchValueInSetWithLowerBound(const std::set<T> &mySet, const T& lowerBound, const T& value) {
    return std::binary_search(std::lower_bound(mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), lowerBound), mySet.end(), value);
```